# How much larger than the fireplace opening should a door kit be?

Tags: fireplace, remodeling

I have a dilemma with sizing my gas fireplace box to fit a new glass door.

The firebox is 40-in W x 23-in H

**Medium glass door**: 30-37-Inch width of firebox opening and 22.5-32.5-Inch height of firebox opening, with 37.5-33-Inch overall frame dimensions.

[image]

**Large glass door**: 36-43-Inch width of firebox opening and 25.5-32.5-Inch height of firebox opening, with 43.5-33-Inch overall frame dimensions.

[image]

So look like my firebox width is OK for Medium but the height of 40-in is higher than the Medium. Is that OK?

Or should I pick Large where both width and height is larger than my current firebox?

What is safe?

Thanks.

Comment: Is yours a prefabricated/factory-built fireplace or is it masonry?

Answer (score 1):

If adding a door kit I would want the frame to be at least 1/2" wider than the opening so it can be sealed with insulation. I use rock wool for the seal because it holds up to the heat.

Comment: If that is the case, Large should work for me. But why they put "25.5-32.5-Inch height" range and not just say something like "max height of 32.5 in"? The number 25.5-in is throwing me off as it's larger than mine which is 23-in